# Is there an exposed/standard Encoding.UTF8NoBOM in .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, .net-4.8

The default `StreamWriter` constructor uses `StreamWriter.UTF8NoBOM`, an internal property, which creates a cached UTF-8 encoder that does not emit the BOM (it also throws on invalid characters, which is not related to this question).

Such an encoding instance can also be created directly with `new UTF8Encoding(false)`.

Is there a .NET Framework property to create a UTF8-no-BOM, in a similar manner as `Encoding.UTF8` returns an encoding equivalent to `new UTF8Encoding(true)`?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be, after searching [the API browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?term=UTF8) and the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/utf8encoding.cs,abd01a5649677f6c,references), but it's possible I missed something. Hard to prove a negative.

Comment: The worst that can happen if you declare a `static readonly` property yourself is that one more object is allocated than strictly necessary. Your application is likely to survive this.

Comment: Even in .NET 6, there is still no Encoding.UTF8NoBOM, but they have now added [Encoding.Latin1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.latin1?view=net-6.0) so maybe you just need to request it be added for .NET 7